# Change variable value and push it after loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have code like this

```
$jumlahcolspan = array();//new array
$horizontaldeep = 5;
$level = array(5,4,3,8,7);//old array
for ($j = 0; $j < $horizontaldeep; $j++) {
    $jml = 1;
    for ($i = $j + 1; $i < $horizontaldeep; $i++) {
        $jml = $level[$i] * $jml;
    }
    array_push($jumlahcolspan, $jml);
}
```

To put it simple, what I want to get is to multiply old array value which index start from `$i+1` to the last and push it to another array.
So, its some thing like this

```
old array:  [5, 4, 3, 8, 7]

new array: [4*3*8*7, 3*8*7, 7, 1]
```

I've tried this but it doesn't work also

```
for ($j = 0; $j < $horizontaldeep; $j++) {
    $jml = 1;
    for ($i = $j + 1; $i < $horizontaldeep; $i++) {
        global $jml;
        $jml = $level[$i] * $jml;
    }
    array_push($jumlahcolspan, $jml);
}
```

Tried this too but not work also.

```
for ($j = 0; $j < $horizontaldeep; $j++) {
     array_push($jumlahcolspan, array_product(array_slice($level, $j+1)));
}
```

Note: now I'm reviewing my full code. May be something not right in my code.
I think the problem is related to `$jml` variable but I can't figure how to solve that. Can anyone help me?

Comment: `for ($j = 0; $j < $horizontaldeep; $j++) {               array_push($jumlahcolspan,array_product(array_slice($level,$j+1)));
            }`

working perfectly. I think the problem occur because I just refreshing the page, not reload the entire page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> One approach would be to use a `Recursive Function` to achieve that goal. The Recursive Function below demonstrates how. And, by the way, you may as well [***quick-test*** it here](https://eval.in/630313).

```
<?php

    $oldArray   = [5,4,3,8,7];

    function arrayMatrixMultiply(array $old, array &$newArray=[]){
        $result     = 1;
        foreach($old as $key=>$value){
            if($key != 0){
                $result*=$value;
            }
        }
        $newArray[] = $result;
        array_splice($old, 0, 1);
        if(!empty($old)){
            // JUST RECURSE TILL THE $oldArray BECOMES EMPTY
            arrayMatrixMultiply($old, $newArray);
        }
        return $newArray;
    }

    $newArray   = arrayMatrixMultiply($oldArray);

    var_dump($newArray);
    // PRODUCES::
    array (size=5)
      0 => int 672
      1 => int 168
      2 => int 56
      3 => int 7
```